# How to fix 2 columns(First and last) present in gridview, and moving columns present in between?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, presentation-layer

I am working with ASP.net 4.0 version. I want to create UI as shown in below image.

1. However I am not sure about controls that I am using are suitable for this UI or not. I am using data repeater control for all collapsible row. Is that correct?
2. If I am using repeater control, then how I can remove a row on a button present on each row?
3. How can I fix columns in grid view
4. How Can I keep moving columns in between fixed column(as shown in figure)

Any kind of guild line will be needful.

THanks,

Tanuja

[image: Image is UI that I wanted to implement.]